# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of 'com.asc.project.service.dto.TaskDataDTO'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postman

I have this error:

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
> `com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.TaskDataDTO` out of START_ARRAY token;
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.TaskDataDTO` out
> of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10,
> column: 21] (through reference chain:
> com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.WorkOrderDTO["taskDataList"])

When post `Json` API, this is my request :

```
    {
    "siteLocationLat": "35.123415",
    "workOrderID": "WO-1rmrud5gkdj4r0n6",
    "siteId": "NNA-12312312311",
    "siteAcessNotes": "No notes",
    "siteLocationLong": "128.910283984",
    "assignedTo": "ibrahem@test.com",
    "timeStamp": 1596738379102,
    "email": "ibrahem@test.com",
    "taskDataList": [
      {
        "roll": "2.0",
        "azimuth": "120.0",
        "tilt": "9.0",
        "sectorLocationLat": "35.123451",
        "amtImei": "35800121213",
        "wakeuUpInterval": "1440",
        "sectorID": "NNA-12312312311-1",
        "sectorLocationLong": "128.123123",
        "taskName": "Install AMT Sector A",
        "taskDescription": "Install AMT on Back of the Antenna"
      }
    ]
    
}
```

My `WorkOrderDto` is:

```
    public class WorkOrderDTO implements Serializable {   
 private  List<TaskDataDTO> taskDataList=new ArrayList<TaskDataDTO>();

    public List<TaskDataDTO> getTaskDataList() {
        return taskDataList;
    }
    public void setTaskDataList(TaskDataDTO taskDataDTO) {
        this.taskDataList.add(taskDataDTO);
    }
}
```

and my WorkOrder Entity is :

```
public class WorkOrder implements Serializable {
    private  List<TaskData> taskDataList=new ArrayList<TaskData>();

    public List<TaskData> getTaskDataList() {
        return taskDataList;
    }

    public void setTaskDataList(TaskData taskData) {
        taskDataList.add(taskData);
    }
}
```

when run my application and request the api and before arrived my controller i see this Exception in postman body :

> JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.TaskDataDTO` out of START_ARRAY token;
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.TaskDataDTO` out
> of START_ARRAY token\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10,
> column: 21] (through reference chain:
> com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.WorkOrderDTO["taskDataList"])

and this error in Java Idea terminal :

> Bad Request: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of
> `com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.TaskDataDTO` out of START_ARRAY token;
> nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot
> deserialize instance of `com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.TaskDataDTO` out
> of START_ARRAY token  at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 10,
> column: 21] (through reference chain:
> com.asc.skyalign.service.dto.WorkOrderDTO["taskDataList"])

Comment: You will need to include the task data dto class here to be helpful - that’s where your error is

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setTaskDataList(TaskDataDTO taskDataDTO) {
        this.taskDataList.add(taskDataDTO);
 }
```

is strange for me, you say that you set the task data list, and you have a taskDataDto in parameter that you add it to the list. `WorkOrderDto` `taskdatalist` getter and setter should be something like this

```
@JsonProperty("taskDataList")
public List<TaskDataList> getTaskDataList() { return taskDataList; }

@JsonProperty("taskDataList")
public void setTaskDataList(List<TaskDataList> value) { this.taskDataList = value; }
```